# Is indented word wrap in jupyter lab possible?

Tags: python, indentation, word-wrap, jupyter-lab

Jupyterlab is doing soft wrap like this (with the setting `"lineWrap": "on"`):

[image: wrong]

But I would prefer something like this, like I have it in all my other text editors (emacs, intellij, vim...):

[image: right]

Is this possible? :)

Answer (score 1):

JupyterLab is using CodeMirror and there is a hack for indentation of soft-wrap lines, published on https://codemirror.net/demo/indentwrap.html.

Code from that page:

```
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    mode: "text/html"
  });
  var charWidth = editor.defaultCharWidth(), basePadding = 4;
  editor.on("renderLine", function(cm, line, elt) {
    var off = CodeMirror.countColumn(line.text, null, cm.getOption("tabSize")) * charWidth;
    elt.style.textIndent = "-" + off + "px";
    elt.style.paddingLeft = (basePadding + off) + "px";
  });
  editor.refresh();
```

It's just a first step and I have no idea how to apply that hack inside JupyterLab (since `CodeMirror` is not a global variable in that environment). I hope someone will be able to build on top of this...

Answer (score -2):

The soft-wrap behaviour seems to be a property of your browser. Since notebook code cells are simply wrapped inside of a `<textarea>`, there is no (simple) solution.

For me on Safari, for example, it's not soft-wrapping at all, rather I get a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled soft-wrap ? Did you put `{     "codeCellConfig": {         "lineWrap": "on",         }, }` in your Notebook -  User preferences?